# Visual Studio unordered_set exception , works on Codeblocks

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, unordered-set

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
    unordered_set<int> mySet;
}MyStruct;

int main(){
    unordered_set<int> sset{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    MyStruct tk;
    tk.mySet = sset;  //This works fine.
    for (auto x : tk.mySet) printf("%d ", x);

    MyStruct *Arr = (MyStruct *)malloc(10* sizeof(MyStruct));

    Arr[0] = tk;  // This isnt working, giving an exception 
                  //the same code runs as expected on codeblocks 

    for (auto x : Arr[0].mySet) printf("%d ", x);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the exception i get when i run the debugger.

> ```
> <fileName>.exe!std::list<int,std::allocator<int>  >::_Orphan_ptr(std::_List_node<int,void *> * _Ptr) Line 1919    C++
> <fileName>.exe!std::list<int,std::allocator<int> >::clear() Line 1501 C++    
> <fileName>.exe!std::_Hash<std::_Uset_traits<int,std::_Uhash_compare<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int> >,std::allocator<int>,0> >::_Copy(const std::_Hash<std::_Uset_traits<int,std::_Uhash_compare<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int> >,std::allocator<int>,0> > & _Right) Line 843    C++    
> <fileName>.exe!std::_Hash<std::_Uset_traits<int,std::_Uhash_compare<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int> >,std::allocator<int>,0> >::operator=(const std::_Hash<std::_Uset_traits<int,std::_Uhash_compare<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int> >,std::allocator<int>,0> > & _Right) Line 291    C++    
> <fileName>.exe!std::unordered_set<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int>,std::allocator<int> >::operator=(const std::unordered_set<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int>,std::allocator<int> > & _Right) Line 187  C++  
> <fileName>.exe!main()  
> [External Code]     
> [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]
> ```

Comment: Where did you read that using `malloc` to create complex class types in C++ would be okay? We need to correct the learning resource you were using.

Comment: I din't know that just playing around it, btw why did that work on gcc ?

Comment: It didn't. It merely _appeared_ to, by pure chance.

Answer (score 4):

```
MyStruct *Arr = (MyStruct *)malloc(10* sizeof(MyStruct));
```

Using `*Arr` or `Arr[i]` in any way is ill-formed no diagnostic required, because no object of type `MyStruct` exists at anywhere `Arr` points.  Simply creating a block of memory large enough to hold an object does not create an object.

Many compilers will let you do this for plain old data types and act as if it is defined behavior (it isn't, but they permit it).

It does not reliably work for non-pod types on any compiler.

```
Arr[0] = tk;  // This isnt working, giving an exception 
              //the same code runs as expected on codeblocks
```

Undefined behavior working is not evidence code is correct.

```
MyStruct *Arr = (MyStruct *)malloc(10* sizeof(MyStruct));

::new( (void*)&Arr[0] ) MyStruct( tk );
```

That is the proper way to construct an object that is a copy of `tk` in a location where no object exists.  Note that you are in charge of manually destroying that object.

You could also:

```
for (int i = i; i < 10; ++i)
  ::new( (void*)(Arr+i) ) MyStruct{};
```

and construct an object in each of the "`MyStruct` size holes".  Then

```
Arr[0] = tk;
```

would be legal.

```
for (auto x : Arr[0].mySet) printf("%d ", x);

return 0;
```

Before you return, you should destroy each object you created as a matter of sanity.

```
Arr[0].~MyStruct();
```

if you only constructed the one, or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  Arr[i].~MyStruct();
```

if you constructed all 10.

Aside:

There are some arguments about if the standard may be a bit ambiguous about if you can take a buffer of size of 10 `MyStruct` and treat it like an array; however, most would consider it a defect if it wasn't possible to do that.

As a general rule, you don't want to use `malloc`'d data to hold non-POD types.  Just call `new MyStruct[10]` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: and btw, how do i realloc on non-POD Types?

Comment: @praveen You don't.  There is no API to extend an allocation block without copying in C/C++, and only "trivially copyable" objects can be safely copied by the realloc procedure.

Comment: @praveen Then again, you could write an allocator that supported a realloc like functionality; it would be a "extend this block if possible".  If it failed, you'd fall back on allocating a *new* block and copying.  However, vector and other standard container wouldn't support it.

Comment: So i can instead do a vector<MyStruct> Arr;   Arr.push_back(tk); and do resize on the vector (if needed), it is completely safe?, thanks

Comment: @praveen `vector` does not `realloc`; it allocates (exponentially larger) buffers and `move`s.  This does not merely copy bytes, but calls the move constructor.  In the case of `MyStruct`, a move will probably copy bytes & clean up the source object so it doesn't think it owns anything -- a few pointers worth of bytes per `unordered_set`, regardless of how big the set is.  It is the logical equivalent of `realloc`, but `realloc` copies bytes without knowing the meaning (copies blindly), while `vector` knows the meaning of the bytes and "does the right thing".